# What does the qstat output jclass mean?

Tags: gridengine

What does the `qstat` output `jclass` mean?

```
$ qstat -help
UGE 8.1.4

$ qstat -u myusername
job-ID  prior   name       user         state submit/start at     queue                          jclass                         slots ja-task-ID 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456 5.87507 AAA        aaaaa        r     01/01/2011 00:11:43 long@aaaaaaaaa.aaa.aa.edu                                        24
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...I was all set to yell at you to read the man page, but it turns out ***this isn't in there*** (Good Job Oracle!), and it's not in the Sun Grid Engine admin guide either (Awesome documentation you guys!)

`jclass` denotes the Job Class to which the job belongs (or blank, as in your example, if the job is not assigned to a job class).

A Job Class is:

> A set of jobs that are equivalent in some sense and treated similarly. In Sun Grid Engine, Enterprise Edition a job class is defined by the identical requirements of the corresponding jobs and the characteristics of the queues being suitable for those jobs.

Comment: Even though I still have no idea what a job class is, like how to use it. But thank you all the same, for at least I know it has nothing to do with me and I can filter this information out with awk.

Comment: And yes, I have checked the manual and found nothing, so I came here to ask. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel I know job classes are describe in the SGE docs - I just don't have the relevant books at my fingertips. Poke around and I'm sure you'll find more details :)